# C Valgrind - Conditional jump depends on unitialitialised value

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, realloc

i want to repair one error..

Valgrind says me this:

```
==9203== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==9203== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9203==    at 0x4C2D64A: strncat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9203==    by 0x400970: newSpeak (main.c:39)
==9203==    by 0x400A62: main (main.c:74)
==9203== 
--9203-- 
--9203-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==9203== 
==9203== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Here is my function newSpeak()

```
int velikost = 0, i = 0, delka = 0;
char * textNovy = NULL;

i = 0;
    while (text[i] != '\0') {
        delka++;
        i++;
    }

textNovy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < delka; i++) {
        textNovy = (char*)realloc(textNovy, ((i+1)+velikost)*sizeof(char) );
        strncat(textNovy, text+i, 1);
    }
return textNovy;
```

value text is given to function from main.
Problem is somewhere in strncat

Thans you!! Lukas

Comment: In `i < delka`, I suspect `delka` is not initialized.

Comment: Do what valgrind says: use `--track-origins=yes` and you'll understand where the problem probably comes from.

Comment: @H2C03 no it's initialized at the top and it doesn't even match the line of the error.

Comment: `double * textNovy` **really** should be `char * textNovy`!

Comment: it matches in strncat - I removed some unimportant lines of code. In strncat is something unitialized, it says.

Comment: @user3052695 Just a suggestion, but rather use strlen to get the string length, don't use a double pointer for text, velikost is just 0 why not use a const, and are you sure the for loop is doing what you want it to do?

Comment: sorry for double/char - I had it only here. Repaired. But it is still same

Comment: Why are you concatenating to the string one letter at a time?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler is right! I have to set some value in textNovy. Thanks to you all! It works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialize the contents of `textNovy`, yet you concatenate on to the end of it.  This leads to the error you are seeing from `valgrind`.

You need at least:

```
textNovy[0] = '\0';
```

(or an equivalent) after the `malloc()`.

Comment: maybe a memset to set the range of memory

Comment: @ojblass: you could use `memset()`, but there's no need; the `strncat()` will set what needs to be set as long as it has a null byte at the start on the first time it is called.

Comment: @user3052695 Why would you allocate a string as small as a `char` ?

Comment: @user9000: I normally wouldn't allocate a single character, but the code does; it is sufficient to get the process started, and isn't formally wrong.  The `realloc()` code increases the space so that (presumably) there is enough space for whatever needs to be stored.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that, sorry.